# Can http protocol be used for urls inside .gitmodules file

Tags: git

When retrieving source code on this particular project, I use this syntax:

```
git clone https://ALerner@path_to_the_gitfile.git
```

I was told to explicitly use credentials as specified above, otherwise I dont have access to the source.

This time around, I have to run this command afterwards:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --merge
```

I went into .gitmodules file, and replaced this syntax:

```
[submodule "src/grpc-proto"]`enter code here`
        path = src/grpc-proto
        url = git@path_to_the_gitfile.git
        branch = .
```

with this one:

```
url = https://ALerner@path_to_the_gitfile.git
```

But now, instead of getting "Access denied" type errors which I was getting before making these credential related changes, I am now getting:

```
Cloning into '/home/alex/go-projects/src/gitlab.n-t.io/webback/developtools'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.n-t.io:sdexnt/developtools-back.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
fatal: clone of 'https://ALerner@gitlab.n-t.io:sdexnt/developtools-back.git' into submodule path '/home/alex/go-projects/src/gitlab.n-t.io/webback/developtools' failed
Failed to clone 'developtools'. Retry scheduled
```

So what syntax do I need to use in .gitmodules file to incorporate my login credential when specifying various submodule paths ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

HTTP URL syntax is different from scp-like. This is the correct URL:

```
https://gitlab.n-t.io/sdexnt/developtools-back.git
```

(`/` instead of `:`)

See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls

Comment: thank you.  if you didnt point out / instead of : I would not have seen it